# Do socket.broadcast.emit('myMessage', data') emit the message to all clients even if some have not set listener to 'myMessage'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to determine the best way to emit an event to some clients without joining room, and just by using listener without emitting to all clients who are connected to the namespace.

For example i want to update the status of some users on the client side by doing something like this:

```
socket.on(`status-changed-${userId}`, myCallback)
```

But the question is: By using socket.broadcast, will the server trying to emit `status-changed-${userId}` to all connected clients even if they have not set `` socket.on(`status-changed-${userId}`, myCallback) ``? Or does socket.io know the clients who are listening to `"status-changed-${userId}"` and will emit only to these clients?

Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do socket.broadcast.emit('myMessage', data') emit the message to all clients even if some have not set listener to 'myMessage'?

Yes.  The server has no idea what clients are listening for a specific message.  When you tell the server to broadcast, that's what it does, whether the client is listening for that specific message or not.

To broadcast only to certain clients, you would have to keep track of a list of clients on the server and broadcast only to that list.  That's one of the things that socket.io rooms are used for because they maintain a list of clients and you can broadcast to a room.

> Or does socket.io know the clients who are listening to "status-changed-${userId}" and will emit only to these clients?

No.  The server has no knowledge of what client messages are being listened to on any given client.  That's a purely client-side thing.

Comment: Thanks very much @jfriend00. So that's to me to know if i want to use more bandwidth or more server RAM. I will use room so, plus i already use clusterisation so it will not be a problem for scaling.